# pcl17 error while loading shared libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently building pcl17 with BUILD_GPU and BUILD_CUDA enabled. When I run the compiled pcl_kinfu_largescale

```
rosrun pcl17 pcl_kinfu_largescale
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/craig/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/bin/pcl_kinfu_largeScale: error while loading shared libraries: libpcl_common.so.1.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, the libraries do exist in the directory perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/build/pcl_trunk/build/lib.

It appears the kinfu binary is being ran in the fuerte_workspace folder, but I'm not sure if that affects the included library. I've also tried running the binary directly from the build folder. I've successfully built the pcl trunk and can run the kinfu binary that way, but I need to incorporate ROS into it so it is not much help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47034/pcl17-error-while-loading-shared-libraries/) by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently this is a known issue within the point cloud library, http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/854

---

Originally posted by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) with karma: 45 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1